# Counting unique filtered values in a column that start with "DOT" or "PRO"

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,

I am working on this exercise where i have to count how many *unique* names start with "DOT" or "PRO" in a column. This has to be made respecting filters that may come from other column. I try to list an example of the table in the pic attached.

[image: Table for Example]

In this example it is possible to only filter by hair, but i may have more columns.

So, let's say i do not apply any filter:

- PRO = 2;
- DOT = 1.

Filtering for Black hair:

- PRO = 0;
- DOT = 1

I hope I've explained what i need completely, and i thank you in advance for the help!

P.S. An excel formula would be perfect, but VBA code is useful as well.

Comment: I'm sorry for the incompleteness. I am currently using this formula to count how many PRO are present in the NAME column: =SOMMA(SE(SINISTRA($A2:$A14;3)="PRO";SUBTOTALE(3;SCARTO(A2;SEQUENZA(RIGHE(A2:A14))-1;)))) This works with filters, but cannot distinguish unique names. (If there are 2 DOT - Mario it will output 2, but i need a 1, because that's the same person.)

Comment: What version of excel do you have?

Comment: 2008 version for Office 365

Comment: So try things like `=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A6,(LEFT(A2:A6,4)="PRO ")*(B2:B6="Black"),""))<>""))`

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice solution! I'm trying to settle the formula so that i don't have to  che the filter a priori, I'd like to let the user select the filter that he wants at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Count Text]

This what I try base of what I understand to your question, may be it could help

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately in the column A, names are written as follows: DOT - Claudio (for example). So i have to use the "LEFT" function to check if the the name begins with DOT or PRO, then i should check if the name next to it is unique.

Comment: Are you able to set up your data so you have "DOT" and "PRO" separate from the rest of the name?  So Column A contains DOT/PRO, and Column B contains "Mario, Claudio, Gianni" etc. ?

Comment: Well, that's a nice idea. I'll try to find a solution for a while longer in this way, but I will split the name if it gets too hard. How could i implement a formula if they are split in 2 columns?

Comment: For starters you could do something like this: "=If(And($A1="DOT", $B1=Mario), "Mario", _`enter more If Statements here as needed`_), but this seems like it could get out of control really fast.  What other criteria do you use to judge whether someone is unique in this context?  Do you have a _Last Name_ you could use?  An ID Number?  How does your data get populated?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an [Array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d):

```
{=SUM(IF(LEFT(A:A,3)="DOT",1,0))}
```

To get the brackets around the formula, you need to press ctrl+shift+enter instead of just enter.

If you want to count the unique ones:

```
{=COUNTA(UNIQUE(IF(LEFT(A:A,3)="DOT",A:A,"")))-1}
```

This Array formula creates an array with either the value if it starts with DOT, or an empty string. Then the unique values are counted with UNIQUE and COUNTA. You need to use -1, because all other values are shown as "" and that also counts as a unique value.

Comment: Thank you, this works for counting DOT's, but is there a way to count unique ones?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Alex, this works for the unique ones like the formule i posted up above. I guess now the problem is only to make it work with the filter. From my (very little) experience, i believe a SUBTOTAL is needed somewhere in these formula's. I'm now trying to make this work                                                   
=MATR.SOMMA.PRODOTTO(--VAL.NUMERO(CONFRONTA(RIF.RIGA(A:A)-1;INDICE(CONFRONTA(A:A;A:A;0););0)/((SINISTRA(A:A;4)="PRO ")*SUBTOTALE(3;SCARTO(A:A;RIF.RIGA(A:A)-1;0;1))))) but still having problems with the filtered output

Answer (score 0):

[image: Excel Count]

Might be useful to create a column helper and subtotal and for your filter value.

Comment: Screenshot is ok just as visualization. But for an answer, you should paste the formulas (so that people could use it)  and describe them.

Comment: I might try with this solution later on, thank you very much.